# Wrong answers while trying to analyze stability

Tags: equation-solving, control-systems

I want to analyze the stability of a closed-loop system (with feedback). The idea is to choose a proper gain kc for the controller. The code is the following:

```
Clear[tfm, stableQ, charPoly, AA, BB, kc, A, B, Cc]
A = {{-64.383, 0, -22.35, 0}, {0, 0, 27.65, -50}, {1788, -2212, 0, 
    0}, {0, 4000, 0, -333.333}};
B = {3619.3, 3619.3, -29800, 0} ;
Cc = {0, 0, 0, 1} ;
AA = A - Outer[Times, B ka kst kc, Cc];
ka = 1/20
BB = B ka kc;
kst = 1/10;


ssm = TransferFunctionModel[
  StateSpaceModel[{AA, Transpose@{BB} , {Cc}}], s]
charPoly = 
 Denominator[SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[ssm][s][[1, 1]]] == 0
stableQ[k_] := AllTrue[s /. NSolve[charPoly /. kc -> k, s], Re[#] < 0 &]

TableForm[Table[{k, stableQ[k]}, {k, 2, 3, 0.1}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"kc", "stableQ"}}]
```

I'm using AA and BB because they are the matrices for the closed-loop system. The table should start returning "False" when the real part of the roots of the char. polynomial are greater or equal zero. However, the table just returns "False" for all the values of kc. That isn't true because if we  get get eigenvalues of AA,there are values of kc that makes the real part less than zero. (i.e for kc <2.6).

Actually, for kc=2,

```
Eigenvalues[AA]
{-188.638 + 612.413 I, -188.638 - 612.413 I, -10.2203 + 
  221.148 I, -10.2203 - 221.148 I}
```

Clearly for kc=2, the real part is negative so the system is stable. But as I said above, when I run the code the table is:

[image]

The results of the table doesn't match what I see with the eigenvalues.

$\textbf{UPDATE}$

I solved it using different commands:

```
Clear[x1, x2, x3, x4, x11, x22, x33, x44, sol1, sol2, yd, AA, kc, BB, \
Cc, B, A, charPoly, ssm, stableQ]
kst = 1/10;
ka = 1/20;
BB = B ka kc;
A = {{-64.383, 0, -22.35, 0}, {0, 0, 27.65, -50}, {1788, -2212, 0, 
    0}, {0, 4000, 0, -333.333}};
B = {3619.3, 3619.3, -29800, 0} ;
Cc = {0, 0, 0, 1} ;
AA = A - Outer[Times, B ka kst kc, Cc];
(*NRoots[Re[Eigenvalues[A-Outer[Times,B ka kst kc,Cc]]] \[Equal]0,kc]
FindInstance[Re[Eigenvalues[A-Outer[Times,B ka kst kc,Cc]]]<0,kc,Reals]
Eigenvalues[A-Outer[Times,B ka kst 210,Cc]]*)
\
(*ssm=TransferFunctionModel[StateSpaceModel[{A,Transpose@{B}ka kc \
kst,{Cc}}],s];
charPoly=Denominator[SystemsModelFeedbackConnect[ssm][s][[1,1]]]\
\[Equal]0;
*)
Charpol = CharacteristicPolynomial[AA, s]
stableQ[k_] := AllTrue[s /. NSolve[Charpol /. kc -> k, s], Re[#] < 0 &]
TableForm[Table[{k, stableQ[k]}, {k, 2, 3, 0.1}], 
 TableHeadings -> {{}, {"kc", "stableQ"}}]
```

I still don't know why it didn't work with the original code but this time I got the correct table:
[image]

Comment: `stableQ[k_] := AllTrue[s /. NSolve[char /. kc -> k, s], Re[#] < 0 &]` I do not see `char` defined any where in your code.

Comment: Your `kst` is undefined.

Comment: `however if I get the Eigenvalues for, say, k=0.8` it is not clear what you are referring to. eigenvalue of what? Can you show what you did there? Please add more words to make the description clear.  It is clear that the roots of your char poly for the closed loop system is not stable for these gains you selected?

Comment: @Nasser updated ! Does it make more clear?

Comment: The reason your stability is different in the two cases is because your poynomials charPol form the original and charPoly from the later case are different.